# How to access the device USB through the browser - ASP .NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have the following question, how can I access a device / equipment connected to the client's usb through an application made in Asp .Net MVC? The idea is to access a biometric reader connected to the customer's computer.

I have already looked for some alternatives such as *ActiveX* and *Silverlight*, but from what I researched ActiveX works only in I.E and Silverlight seems outdated (at least the tutorials and research related to the subject). I saw that it is possible to work this way with Blazor and Asp .Net Core, but it would be impracticable to change the project at the moment. I thank anyone who can help.

Comment: Do you need to access the usb port from the client (e.g. from code running in the browser) or do you want to expose a usb on the server side to the client?

Comment: Hello @sommmen, I want to access the client's USB port.

Comment: You don't really need Blazor, what you want to look for is the [HTML5 usb api](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/03/access-usb-devices-on-the-web).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately accessing a client's usb could be a tad hard. Browsers generally tend to be sandboxed against hackers. So you can't access hardware devices that easily. Even for accessing a camera the client needs to give explicit permission.

More and more webapi's incoroporate native behaviour however, and one of this is apperently chrome:

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/03/access-usb-devices-on-the-web

Firefox also seems to do its part:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/USB

But be careful, because some limitations may apply. For example, HTTPS seems to be a must-have.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I will study this alternative and try to apply it to my project.